# how do you print to .csv for each ID in Python

Tags: python, regex, csv, url

```
import urllib
import re
import csv

player_code = open("Desktop/OHL PYTHON/test2.txt").read()

player_code = player_code.split("\r")

for pc in player_code:
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen( "http://www.eliteprospects.com/iframe_player_stats_small.php?player="+pc+"")

    htmltext = htmlfile.read()  
    regex = '<font color="#000099">(.+?)</font>'  
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    team = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    data = pc, team


    with open('my_games.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['pc', 'team','League', 'Gp', 'G','A','P','Pims']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter= ":",
                                extrasaction ='ignore')
        i=0
        writer.writeheader()
        for pc in player_code:
            writer.writerow({'pc':[pc],'team':[team]})
            i+=1
```

This is only returning one line of data over and over. Any direction would be helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should open file before the for loop or use `a+` mode. `w` opens the file and truncate its data each time it is opened.

```
with open('my_games.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for pc in player_code:
```

or

```
with open('my_games.csv', 'a+') as csvfile
```

Opening file once would be a better approach.

Since you are looping twice for writing data you have multiple lines. Just remove

```
i=0
for pc in player_code:
    writer.writerow({'pc':[pc],'team':[team]})
        i+=1
```

And instead just have and i think it will work.

```
writer.writerow({'pc':[pc],'team':[team]})
```

Comment: Thank you. This is now giving me the all the data I need. It is however still producing multiple lines of each, instead of 1 line for each id. Any suggestions? Thank you again! Im so close! @Ashish